# POST to API/tokens takes care of new tokens, How to return data to the caller?

Tags: rest, api-design

I've been doing some study on REST API design best practices. I come from an RPC client/server background.
I have the following questions:

My service revolves around a single object - a Token.

On creating a new token, a unique tokenID is automatically generated for that token, which is all that needs to be sent back to the client.

The other fields that make up a token are its value, ownerId and status. At the point of creation, the token status is 'new'.

I understand that a POST to /API/tokens should take care of creating a new token, but what data do i return to the caller?

1. 201 created header
2. a json object representing the token with all it's fields
3. a json object with just the new tokenID and status (which is all the caller really needs)
4. a link to the new "token resource" - this seems silly, as it would require a further GET to return the actual token

At this point i'm considering 1) and 3)

Comment: actually its a long question i had posted here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/api-craft/7wSM8jaQ9ZM

Comment: @RobertHarvey c) makes sense, that's my choice too, but what is the expected "Standard" REST response?

Comment: 201 Created.  You already knew the answer to this; I think you just wanted confirmation.  Well, now you have it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, if you read my post on groups.google APi-craft you will see that this has been giving me a lot of concern. I've been studying far and wide - trying to learn how to get REST "done properly". It helps to have other opinions - confirmation is cool too. Thanks.

Comment: You may be overthinking it.  There's nothing wrong with returning the entire token, and while Kijana's suggestion to simply return `401 gone` seems sloppy to me, your API would still work anyway.

Comment: Yeah i have issues with one of Kijana's suggestions too. If you request for a token that does not exist (anymore) ... is that not 404? "no such resource here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The w3c spec for [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) has:

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header

So I'd go for a) and c) too...

Comment: so basically you are not returning the full resource object but just the relevant fields that were created , ie, the ID and the status. Thanks for the link to the w3c spec